Unable to make Axios call in AWS Node js lambda
I am trying to make an API call using axios inside request.on  in a Node AWS lambda function.
Issue:
The first time when the /responseHandler is called, the axios code inside it does not executed. But when the /responseHandler is called again the axios code which had to happen the first time gets executed now. The code works fine when tried in local environment. The issue occurs only in lambda.
Adding only necessary code of each page
index.js
const serverless = require('serverless-http')
var reqHandler = require('./requestHandler.js'),
    resHandler = require('./responseHandler.js'
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.post('/requestHandler', function (request, response){
    reqHandler.postReq(request, response);
});

app.post('/responseHandler', function (request, response){
        resHandler.postRes(request, response);
});

module.exports.handler = serverless(app)

in requestHandler.js there are some logic and I store few global variables to be used in responseHandler.js
responseHandler.js
const axios = require('axios')
exports.postRes = function(request,response){
    request.on('data',  (data) => {
        var encryption = 'somelogic';
            
        axios.post(`https://solution.com/handler?encResp=${encryption}`, {})
            .then((response) => {
                axios.post(`https://solution.com/txn?orderId=${global.orderId}`, {},headers: {'Authorization': global.token,}})
                .then(response => {})
                .catch(error => {})
            })
            .catch(err => {})
        });
    
    request.on('end', function () {
        response.write(htmlcode);
        response.end();
    });     
};

i am not able to make the axios calls inside request.on('data' loop.
Workaround:

Tried adding axios layer in lambda
used aync await
tried http or fetch
tried adding a timeout

Can anyone please help me on this? Or is this the right approach?
